# Simple Stokes Theorem problem

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

$\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$Use Stokes theorem to evaluate
$$
\iint_\Sigma y \dd{y} \dd{z} + z \dd{z} \dd{x} + x \dd{x} \dd{y}
$$
where $\Sigma$ is upper half-sphere oriented outwardly. Hint:
$$
(y,z,x) = \text{Curl}(-xy, -yz, -zx)
$$

---

Now, I've used Stokes Theorem and the hint:
$$
\iint_\Sigma y \dd{y} \dd{z} + z \dd{z} \dd{x} + x \dd{x} \dd{y} = \oint_\Gamma -xy  \dd{x} - yz \dd{y} - zx \dd{z}
$$
but I instantly got stuck. What should I do next? I know how to calculate line integrals, but only when parametrization is given. $\Gamma$ seems to be circle with arbitrary radius R, but I can't think of any parametrization which would take `z` into account.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circle is used because that is the boundary of the upper-half sphere.  Because that circle is in the $xy-$ plane, $z=0$.  A parameterization of the circle could then be
$$x=\cos t$$
$$y=\sin t$$
$$z=0$$